# Asynchronous send and receive using datagramSockets in java

Tags: java, sockets, asynchronous

I am new to Socket programming in java, but quite familiar with the .NET socket programming.
I wanted to know that, how can we asynchronously exchange(send/receive) the packets/messages using datagramsockets in java. Like C# provides [BeginSend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h44aee9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [BeginReceive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxkwh6zw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods for this purpose , Does java also provide something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for NIO DatagramChannel.  A quick google search on that will turn up a tutorial.  There are also frameworks (like Apache Mina) that make NIO a bit easier.

Comment: Nothing asynchronous in there. Non-blocking, yes: asynchronous, no.

Comment: Apache MINA does have a callback type model where you code gets invoked when datagrams come in (see https://mina.apache.org/mina-project/userguide/ch2-basics/sample-udp-server.html).  It's not exactly like the Begin* methods in .net (ie once the handler is setup in mina, it's automatic), but it is more or less what was asked for.

Comment: But DatagramChannel on its own doesn't do that, so it isn't what he's looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Much to my surprise, Java 7 doesn't have an AsynchronousDatagramChannel, but it does have AsynchronousSocketChannel/ServerSocketChannel.

Comment: hi, Thanks for replying... Can You give me some example or reference ?